# SQL PIVOT syntax is wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Trying to create a view with a PIVOT in it, can't figure out the syntax. The source view has three columns: ClientNameID, Item, and CountOfItem. I want ClientNameID to be the row, Item to be the column, and CountOfItem to be the value.

[image: This the view I tried]

Comment: please refer to the books online https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx on proper syntax for PIVOT

Comment: @Squirrel Genius. I can't imagine why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
SELECT        clientnameid
FROM            dbo.vAggregateSalesByCustomerAndItem
pivot (
    Sum(countOfItem) FOR Item in ([Ring])
) PivotTable
```

The problem was syntax ***BUT*** I also learned that the dimensions (columns) must be hard-coded in the DML. I wanted to get the dimensions dynamically from a table, which is do-able in Excel, with a column range, but not here.

Comment: to get dimensions dynamcally, you will required `Dynamic SQL` You can query `sys.columns` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the list of column names

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this. its worked for you..

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Item 
                      from dbo.vAggregateSalesByCustomerAndItem
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    ,1,1,'')

 set @query = 'SELECT clientnameid ' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select clientnameid,countOfItem,Item 
            from dbo.vAggregateSalesByCustomerAndItem
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            Sum(countOfItem)
            for Item in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

   execute(@query);
```